# how to write a comparison operator for struct containing map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have structure like :

```
   struct MyStruct
    {

    char *name;
    map<char*,char*> mymap;//assume that this map insert data in increasing order
    };
```

I have another map :

```
    map<MyStruct,int,Compare> mTest;

    //compare function for less then operator
    struct Compare
    : public std::binary_function<MyStruct, MyStruct, bool>
    {
        bool operator()(const MyStruct &a, const MyStruct&b)
        {
            if(strcmp(a.name,b.name)< 0)
                return true;
            else if(strcmp(a.name,b.name)==0)
            {
                //How should I compare map `mymap` ??
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So How should I write compare for `mymap` ?

This is what basically I want :

Two maps are equal if

1. there name are equal
2. Their maps size are equal
3. then content of map should be equal i.e both their key and value.

Comment: You should use C++ syntax, first of all. `elseif` is no C++, and your `if` is missing a closing paren. Then it depends completely on how you would two maps to be sorted properly. It's up to you. The only thing is you should make sure it is a strict ordering.

Comment: @ArneMertz I have updated above code. Lets assume that `mymap` store data in increasing order. Now how could I compare two maps in `Compare` function?

Comment: Firstly, `if(strcmp(a.name<b.name))` is broken... even if the `<` is meant to be `,` - that's whenever they're different and you need to return `true` only if `a < b` in your desired ordering (i.e. `if strcmp(a.name, b.name) < 0)`.  Secondly, how can we tell you how to compare the maps?  You could say whichever has the lowest distinct value should compare `<`, or take an average, or check the number of entries in the `map` etc..  Until you say what makes sense for your purposes, we can only offer alternatives with no understanding of what's useful to you.

Comment: You could compare their sizes, or their elements or whatever you like, that depends on what you want to achieve. Please edit your post and tell us in what context you need to compare `MyStruct`s.

Comment: Just use a class and look for custom operators in c++

Comment: @EoiFirst: while that's often good, it's not necessarily the case that the ordering in this particular `map` will be meaningful and wanted in other usage, or that indeed any order will be universally useful through a program, so learning to implement a separate comparison functor is legitimate.  Anyway, it would move but not resolve any of the problems Vinay's having implementing the comparison.

Comment: You have to define what less means. Eg: the string "Hello" is less than "Z" - similar might apply to your maps.

Comment: @Vinay one thing to take into account: having `char*` as the map's key means it is sorted by the addresses, i.e. the pointer values. So it is *not* sorted by the string's contents as you might want. This is another reason to use `std::string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can order maps. Three things have to be taken into account: size of the maps, the keys, and the values. Since a map itself ordered by the keys already, it's only natural to compare values after keys. So, given two maps of the same size, only the keys will matter. I will use integer keys and values for an easier example:

```
 map1: 1->42       map2: 5->16     map3: 1->44   map4: 1->42
       2-> 5             6->16           2->67         2-> 7
       7-> 8             7-> 8           3->10         7-> 8
```

Now, comparing map1 and map2 is easy: the first key of map1 is lower than the first key of map2, so map1 should come first.
Comparing map1 and map3 gives the same key in the first entry, but the corresponding value is lower for map1, so map1 comes first again.
Comparing map1 and map4 shows that the first key-value pair is entirely the same, but comparing the second pair shows that map1 comes first, because its value is lower again.

The order by size is trivial again. A map with smaller size comes before one with bigger size.

Now it is completely up to you, if you want to sort by size first or by key/values first.
Consider an additional map:

```
map5: 5->16
      7-> 3
```

The size of map5 is 2, the size of map1 is 3. So if you order by size first, map5 comes before map1. If you compare the elements first, map1 comes before map5, because the first element is lower.

This comparison is already available in C++: `std::pair` provides an `operator<` that compares keys first and values after. The element-wise comparison of a collection of elements in general is done vía `std::lexicographical_compare`. In addition, `std::map` provides an `operator<` that does the lexicographical comparison for you. It compares elements first, sizes second.

However, in your case, since you are using `char*`s instead of C++'s `string`s, you'd have to write your own comparator for the `pair<char*, char*>` which are the elements of your map. I'd advice using strings alltogether, the it becomes very straightforward, because `std::string` provides an `operator<`:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  string name;
  map<string, string> mymap;
};


map<MyStruct,int,Compare> mTest;

//compare function for less then operator
struct Compare
{
  bool operator()(const MyStruct &a, const MyStruct&b)
  {
    return a.name < b.name //name first
      || (a.name == b.name && cmp(a.mymap, b.mymap));
  }

  bool cmp(map<string, string> const& lhs, map<string, string> const& rhs)
  {
    return lhs.size() < rhs.size() //size first
      || (lhs.size() == rhs.size() && lhs < rhs); 
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `char*` is frankly horrible and outdated. Use `std::string`, your class becomes:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  std::string name;
  map<std::string, std::string> mymap;
};
```

Now, for a map, you need to provide the *less-than* operator, for example:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  std::string name;
  map<std::string, std::string> mymap;

  friend bool operator<(MyStruct const& lhs, MyStruct const& rhs)
  {
    // Now the comparison is easier - use the defaults!
    if (lhs.name < rhs.name)
      return true;
    return lhs.mymap < rhs.mymap; // this does a lexicographical comparison of all values.
  }
};
```

Then your map of structures becomes:

```
std::map<MyStruct, int> mTest;
```

No need for cumbersome code.

EDIT: Just noticed your update, you can implement the other operators for `MyStruct` and compose them as I've done above from calling the logical operators of `name` and `mymap`, you don't need to implement any custom hacks yourself.